# How can I recover from vaadin's 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, tomcat, vaadin

I'm using Win7, Java 1.8, eclipse Luna 4.4.2, Tomcat 8, and have just started exploring Vaadin's Touchkit to write a mobile browser application. I also have Chrome as my default browser, both on my Win7 machine and for servlet-based apps in eclipse.

It's going pretty well, it looks - or has looked - like I'll be able to complete a little application in 80-100 hours of effort or so. At least, if I can figure out how to keep from having to wrestle with the Vaadin environment and plug-in.

I have developed a pattern to my development; In order to make coding changes, I do the following:

1. stop the Server
2. make the coding changes
3. execute the maven 'install' goal (right-click project, select 'debug as', select 'maven install'). This (usually) compiles the project and deploys it to the Tomcat server configured to run with eclipse (and set as the default server).
4. execute 'debug on server' (right-click project, select 'debug as', select 'run on server'.

I've been doing this all day -- probably have done it 50 times since I got up. It's been working.

I have some resource files -- JPGs and text files -- that are used in the application. They are static (so far), i.e., the application reads them once to create classes with those data, and they are not changed during the running of the app. I use tools other than eclipse to alter them -- create new ones, change ones that are there, etc. After I make such changes, I select the project in "Project Explorer" and press F5; as I understand it, this refreshes the files under the project so that they are synchronized with the files on the file system.

Twice now, after making some changes, the above no longer works the way it did. Executing "debug on server" does not deploy the app, and I get "resource not available" from Chrome and discover that the application is not deployed there.

Once I deploy it manually, sometimes it works, but more often it starts giving an error like this:

> Widgetset 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain implementation for 
>   com.vaadin.addon.touchkit.ui.NavigationManager. Check its component 
>   connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and 
>   re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package,
>    you might want to refer to add-on instructions.

I have not installed any add-ons during the process; I've seen references to re-compiling a widgetset, but am not sure how to do it in eclipse because it hasn't been necessary. One of the configurations for maven/touchkit indicates that widgetset compilation is automatic.

I have tried removing the application, cleaning the server work folders, cleaning the server (whatever that actually means), cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, re-deploying the project, and running it again -- I get the same result.

After the first time it did it, not knowing it has been connected with Chrome and wanting to get on with things, and suspecting I just did something wrong, I created a new eclipse workspace, created a new project, and copied source code into new classes to recreate the application from scratch. I hope I don't have to keep doing that, it doesn't seem like I should.

I see vague things on the net about how this is specific to Chrome, and indeed, this time, if I run the app on my phone it seems to work fine, also on Firefox.

Is there a way to reset Chrome so that this will work there as well? It's what I'm used to and what I want to keep using, I'd hate to have to change my browser for this. Besides, this really seems like something is wrong that someone should fix, and until they get to that, it would be nice to at least have a workaround.

Does anyone else get this error? Have they discovered a way to get the Chrome environment reset so I don't have to switch to Firefox and hope it doesn't happen there?

Comment: Try maven -> plugins -> vaadin -> compile. Then maven -> package and them debug on server

Comment: If you'll please put that in an answer, I'll accept it -- that worked. I thought the maven 'install' goal would have included any 'compile' operation that was needed. Actually, all I did was execute maven build... and typed in 'compile' for the operation. Gotta write this down somewhere...

Comment: Well, it worked the first time, and it got me running on incognito chrome again; still got the error the second time I ran after rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

maven -> plugins -> vaadin -> compile.

Then maven -> package and then debug on server

Comment: All right, now I'm confused, sorry -- where is "maven" in this context? I right-clicked on the project and selected "Maven", but there is no "plugins" option from there.

Comment: I have m2e installed -- is there supposed to be a "Maven" menu bar option?

Comment: Do you have vaadin plugin for eclipse? Also read this https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-eclipse.html#gwt.eclipse.compiling

Comment: More details: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/addons.compiling.html

Comment: Yes, am using vaadin plugin for eclipse, and started the project with the maven touchkit archetype. I've been cleaning and recompiling for 15 minutes now, but the browser always reports that the resource is not available. I don't understand what I've done differently, or how it works so that I can make it work that way again. I'll read the documentation you've pointed me to, and thanks for the answers; I do wish it at least seemed deterministic, instead of having to use trial-and-error to find something that works.

Comment: ok, one of those links starts out talking about writing a widget component, which I don't need as far as I know. It then talks about compiling the widgetset; I don't know if I needed to do this or not, but there's a button for it, so I clicked that and it appeared to complete normally. But I'm still getting "resource not available", even after I stop the server, remove the app, run maven clean, compile the widget set, do maven compile, do maven install, add the component, and restart the server. Is there a place that tells me what must be cleaned out under what circs, and the order for ops?

Comment: Are you doing this in that order: 1. maven clean 2. complile widgetset 3. maven package(or install)? Also try Ctrl + F5 in your browser, it will clear the caches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127485/discussion-between-arcy-and-krzysztof-majewski).